# Swift: Algorithm to determine which section to render cell

Tags: algorithm, uitableview, swift

I have been scratching my head over this for the past couple of hours.  I'm working on a system which could grow in the future as more categories for game preferences are added, therefore I need to devise an algorithm to determine which cell belongs in which section.

My data model looks something like:

```
[Games]     [Category]
GameA    -  CategoryC
GameB    -  CategoryA
GameC    -  CategoryB
GameD    -  CategoryA
```

The above data model sample is to demonstrate that there is no guaranteed order for the games and there respective categories to be stored.

So far I have tried the following:

```
let section = indexPath.section
let row     = indexPath.row
let offset  = tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(section)

let game = gameTypes[(section * offset-1) + row]
```

I thought that the above would work as:

```
Section 0 with 2 rows = 
   Row 0: 0 * 1 + 0 = 0 (OK)
   Row 1: 0 * 1 + 1 = 1 (OK)

Section 1 with 3 rows =
   Row 0: 1 * 2 + 0 = 2 (OK)
   Row 1: 1 * 2 + 1 = 3 (OK)
   Row 2: 1 * 2 + 2 = 4 (OK)

Section 2 with 2 rows =
   Row 0: 2 * 1 + 0 = 2 (NO, should be 5)
   Row 1: 2 * 1 + 1 = 3 (NO, should be 6)

...
```

The algorithm above is clearly flawed once it reaches Section 2, how would I fix this? Or do Apple provide a more efficient way for handling this?

**NOTE** A cell can only belong in a section if it is of Category X

Comment: The problem is general is that your model sucks. You just have a "flat" model sitting there like a dead fish. :) You need to structure the model so that it _consists_ of sections and rows just like the table view.

Comment: You should use a 2D array

Comment: You could even create a custom object to hold your data. It can contain methods to get games out of it. Or to check where a game is in it etc... Build it either from arrays or dictionaries or a combination of both or something else. If you are just displaying the info then try to create a model that matches the view.

Comment: @Fogmeister I thought of that too, but the problem is that his categories are not fixed and static in advance, so he needs room to grow.

Comment: @Alex Here is a typical section-and-row data model, an example from my book: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch08p416sections/ch21p718sections/RootViewController.swift

Comment: Thanks Matt I'll give that a read

Comment: @Alex note that we use array of arrays so that at `cellFor...` time we can just say `self.sectionData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]`, badda-bing badda-boom.

Comment: I tried to use a Dictionary earlier but it was causing problems (I believe they're immutable)? So a 2D Array would be a better solution - don't know why I hadn't thoguht of that...embarassing :P

Comment: a 2D array as mentioned also by matt is your best option